# GWT Send form parameters to a servlet

Tags: gwt

I´m trying to catch the next two highlighted fields in a servlet where I can get the uploaded file.

The source code is just the same as which is shown in a [GWT FormSubmit class Javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html)

```
form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);

// Create a panel to hold all of the form widgets.
VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
form.setWidget(panel);

// Create a TextBox, giving it a name so that it will be submitted.
final TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.setName("WorkTitle");
tb.setValue("WorkTitle");

panel.add(tb);

// Create a ListBox, giving it a name and some values to be associated
// with
// its options.
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
lb.setName("listBoxFormElement");
lb.addItem("foo", "fooValue");
lb.addItem("bar", "barValue");
lb.addItem("baz", "bazValue");
panel.add(lb);

// Create a FileUpload widget.
FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
upload.setName("uploadFormElement");
panel.add(upload);

// Add a 'submit' button.
panel.add(new Button("Submit", new ClickListener() {
    public void onClick(Widget sender) {
        form.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"uploadWork");
        form.submit();
    }
}));
```

I´m getting these parameters with this code lines in my servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("ENTRAA BIENNNN");
    System.out.println(" ___ELEMENTO1" + req.getAttribute("WorkTitle"));
    System.out.println(" ___ELEMENTO3" + req.getParameterValues("WorkTitle"));
```

But both returns me `NULL`.

How could I do?

TIA!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most servlet containers do not decode `multipart/form-data` automatically, so `req.getParameter` (or `getParameterValues` or similar getters) won't return anything.
You'll have to use a library such as [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/), or [Jetty's `MultiPartFilter`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Servlets_Bundled_with_Jetty#MultiPartFilter) to decode `multipart/form-data` payload.

As a side note, `req.getAttribute` has nothing to do with getting data out of the request; it's used to pass data, related to a request, between server components (between the servlet container and servlets, or between a filter and a servlet, for instance)

Comment: Ok, I Understand. I´m using Apache Commons FileUpload, in fact I get the file on server side. The problem is that I don´t know how to include the title and the comment of this file., that comes from the same form.

Comment: You have to loop over the parsed items and use `isFormField`. See http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html#Processing_the_uploaded_items or http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html#Parsing_the_request