# Getting FormPanel's field values

Tags: gwt, servlets, field, return-value

I'm having problems with getting the value of the fields coming from a FormPanel. Theonly thing I get is the image included in the form here is the servlet code, I'm using Apache Commons:

```java
    // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload1 = new ServletFileUpload();

        // Parse the request
        FileItemIterator iter;
        try {
            iter = upload1.getItemIterator(req);
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItemStream item = iter.next();
                String name = item.getFieldName();
                InputStream stream = item.openStream();
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    System.out.println("Form field " + name + " with value "
                        + Streams.asString(stream) + " detected.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("File field " + name + " with file name "
                        + item.getName() + " detected.");
                    // Process the input stream

                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324028/gwt-send-form-parameters-to-a-servlet) but it didn't really explain what to do

Comment: Can you share the FormPanel and the inputs you'd added inside of that? If not, can you confirm that you've set the name property of each field?

Comment: Use FireBug or similar tool to analyze your request and see if form field values are included in the request. Then debug and check servlet code if HttpServletRequest has all those parameters.

Comment: Thank you both!! As a matter of fact, I didn't put the name property! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Like @Colin Alworth said, the name property must be set for each field!

```
TextBox lastName = new TextBox();
lastName.setName("LastName");
```